# C# throwing assertion after if?

Tags: c#

In my code I have a loop with an if condition, checking for out of bounds. In production I only want to call continue if this happens but in debug I would like to throw an assertion for the developer. How do I do this?

```
int x = 10;
if(x > 5){

//assert

continue;

}
```

I have simplified the condition above, in reality its about 4 different parameters I check.

Answer (score 0):

See [Debug.Assert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.assert). It will “be disabled” in a production build without the DEBUG define.

> Checks for a condition; if the condition is *false*, outputs messages and displays a message box that shows the call stack.

> By default, the Debug.Assert method works only in debug builds. Use the Trace.Assert method if you want to do assertions in release builds.

Example. Note the “flipped” logic:

```
Debug.Assert(x <= 5);
```

This same behavior can be added to a custom method via a [ConditionalAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute). For example, one could create a “MyAssert” to write to a log file.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, you can do like this. By default, the Debug.Assert method works only in debug builds.

The following example checks whether the type parameter is valid. If type is null, Assert outputs a message.

```
public static void MyMethod(Type type, Type baseType) {
    Debug.Assert(type != null, "Type parameter is null");

   // Perform some processing.
 }
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.assert?view=netcore-3.1